# not getting a Winsock error when ethernet unplugged

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, winsock2

I'm working on a client application that sends sensor data one way to a remote server. After the initial login there is no return data from the server. My problem is when the ethernet is disconnected such as a hard disconnect i.e. wireless link goes down, my application does not get a error return value after attempting a 'send' call. I am using a single non-blocking socket instance. The thread checks for a 'recv' each loop using 'select'. It does eventually get an error on 'recv' but never on 'send'. 
When the remote PC has a internet connectivity loss it will cause the program to be disconnected from the server for minutes to hours before it recognises the connection loss happened and switches to re-login the server. What can be done to help detect the hard disconnect?

```
void checkConnect(NTRIP& server)
{
//1st check for recv or gracefully closed socket
char databuf[SERIAL_BUFFERSIZE];
fd_set Reader, Writer, Err;
TIMEVAL Timeout;
Timeout.tv_sec = 1; // timeout after 1 seconds
Timeout.tv_usec = 0;
FD_ZERO(&Reader);
FD_ZERO(&Err);
FD_SET(server.socket, &Reader);
FD_SET(server.socket, &Err);
int iResult = select(0, &Reader, NULL, &Err, &Timeout);
if(iResult > 0)
{
    if(FD_ISSET(server.socket, &Reader) )
    {
        int recvBytes = recv(server.socket, databuf, sizeof(databuf), 0);
        if(recvBytes == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cout << "socket error on receive call from server " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            closesocket(server.socket);
            server.connected_IP = false;
        }
        else if(recvBytes == 0)
        {
            cout << "server closed the connection gracefully" << endl;
            closesocket(server.socket);
            server.connected_IP = false;
        }
        else  //>0 bytes were received so read data if needed
        {

        }
    }
    if(FD_ISSET(server.socket, &Err))
    {
        cout << "select returned socket in error state" << endl;
        closesocket(server.socket);
        server.connected_IP = false;
    }
}
else if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    cout << "ip thread select socket error " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    closesocket(server.socket);
    server.connected_IP = false;
}
//2nd check hard disconnect if no other data has been sent recently
if(server.connected_IP == true && getTimePrecise() - server.lastDataSendTime > 5.0)
{
    char buf1[] = "hello";
    cout << "checking send for error" << endl;
    iResult = send(server_main.socket, buf1, sizeof(buf1), 0);
    if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        int lasterror = WSAGetLastError();
        if(lasterror == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
        {
            cout << "server send WSAEWOULDBLOCK" << endl;
        }
        if(lasterror != WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
        {
            cout << "server testing connection send function error " << lasterror << endl;
            closesocket(server.socket);
            server.connected_IP = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "sent out " << iResult << " bytes" << endl;
    }

    server.lastDataSendTime = getTimePrecise();
}
```

}

Comment: TCP is based on the assumption that the connection is *reliable*.   That makes it very, very efficient, you can dump a bunch of data to transmit with send() and the protocol stack does everything it can to get that data delivered.  Later, not bogging down your program.  You don't have to *wait* until the "okay, it got there" acknowledgement is received.  Extraordinarily important, latency kills perf dead.  Which of course means that the "it doesn't work anymore" news gets delivered late as well.  You can't be sure until you call shutdown().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to detect disconnect until you try to send something.
The solution for you is the following:

1. You detect that you have received no data for a certain period of time and you want to check is the connection is alive.
2. You send some data to the server using `send` function. It could be protocol-specific ping packet or either garbage. The `send` function returns immediately, because it does not wait for actual data send. It only fills internal send buffer.
3. You begin waiting for socket read.
4. While you are waiting, OS tries to send the data in the send buffer to the server.
5. When OS detects that it cannot deliver data to the server, then the connection is marked as erroneous.
6. Now you will get an error when calling `recv` and `send` functions.

The send timeout is system specific and can be configured. Usually, it is about 20 seconds (Linux) - 2 minutes (Windows). It means that you need to wait a lot before you receive an error.

Notes:

1. You can also turn on TCP keep alive mechanism, but I don't recommend you to do this.
2. You can also modify TCP timeout intervals. It can be helpful when you want the connection to survive the temporary network disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

That's how TCP works and is intended to work. You will get an error from a subsequent send, but never from the first send after the disconnect. There is buffering, and retry, and retry timeout to overcome before an error is signalled.

Comment: I never get an error from the send function, either of data or the 5 second "hello" string to try to get an error if no data is being sent. I only ever get an error on the recv function. To be clear, if no sensor data is sent for 5 seconds a "hello" message is sent to 'test' the connection. This test still returns no error.

Comment: You will get an error related to a prior send on a subsequent send. A very subsequent send. It can take minutes.